# Quandl download wiki EOD stock prices from python - how to?

Tags: python, quandl

1. Is there a way to do a partial download on Quandl for the Wiki EOD Stock Prices but for a given day in the past - not the most current date e.g. download for 2016-07-20?

Entire database (too large): https://www.quandl.com/data/WIKI/documentation/bulk-download

Just the last day: https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases/WIKI/data?api_key=myAPIkey&download_type=partial

One day in the past for all stocks: ?????

2. Can this download be triggered from python code to a specified folder? How would one do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It does not seem possible according to Quandl. There is no parameter for the date. Only partial or complete.
2. The python code is:

import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'XXXXX'
quandl.bulkdownload("WIKI",download_type="partial",filename="./WIKI.zip")

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
data = quandl.get("WIKI/AAPL", 
                  trim_start = "2010-01-01", 
                  trim_end = "2013-01-01", 
                  authtoken = "your_API_key_here")
```

Comment: this is just for one ticker. i am looking for all tickers at once